# Insert timestamp from dataframe in teradata table

Tags: python, dataframe, types, teradata, sqldatatypes

I have a df that i want to move to a teradata table. I am using a framework that was discussed on this platform. However I am getting a error: (-6760) Invalid timestamp.

```html
create table  name (
    time_st TIMESTAMP(0)
    )


current_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df = df.assign(time=current_time)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']  
print(df)

timestamp in df:
2022-04-11 10:38:44
```

Can someone help me with timestamp am i going wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing that generates the 6760. Please edit the question to include that information as well. By default, SQL `TIMESTAMP` values are mapped to Python `str`. If you are using the current version of the `teradatasql` driver, then you can set `teradata_values` connection parameter to `false` if you want `TIMESTAMP` to map to `datetime.datetime`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add format also?

```
df
       Fee       new              str-time
0    20000     Spark    04/11/2022, 15:04:35
1    25000  Py_Spark    04/11/2022, 15:04:35
```

Add format while converting string to datetime-

```
>>> df["new_time"]=pd.to_datetime(df["str-time"],format='%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S')

>>> df
       Fee       new              str-time            new_time
0    20000     Spark    04/11/2022, 15:04:35   2022-04-11 15:04:35
1    25000  Py_Spark    04/11/2022, 15:04:35   2022-04-11 15:04:35
```